# Matlab: vectorize this for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, sum

I have a for loop which takes forever to evaluate (because it involves long vectors) and I'm hoping it could be faster if I vectorize, but I can't see how.

The problem is to take a vector A of size M+N-1 and make a new vector B of size N where the first element is the sum of the first M elements of A, the second element is element 2 to M+1 of A and so on. In a for loop I write

```
B=zeros(1,N);
for i=1:N
    B(i)=sum(A(i:M+i-1));
end
```

Do you see a way to vectorize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
conv(A, ones(M,1), 'valid');
```